# Find all real numbers $x$ such that: $\lfloor 7x\rfloor = 7$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm not quite sure how to approach this. Does $x$ have to be very small for it to work?

Answer (score 5):

$\lfloor7x\rfloor=7$ means $7\le7x<8$, I'm sure you can solve it from here.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more? I can solve from there, but how can you make that assumption?

Comment: That is exactly what $\lfloor\ \rfloor$ means, there is really nothing to explain.

Comment: How would it be different if the problem was 7⌊x⌋= ⌊7x⌋ ?

Comment: That would be significantly different, suggest you ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @banana Well, try solving that equation and compare the results.

Comment: @banana Let $x=n+r$ where $n\in\mathbb N, r\in [0,1)$ and solve $7\lfloor n+r \rfloor = \lfloor 7n+7r \rfloor$

Comment: @banana $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for a real number $x$ means "the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$"; the inequality that David wrote follows from that

Comment: If $7x$ were not between $7$ and $8$ as described by David, it would be greater than or equal to $8$ in which case it would floor to something $8$ or larger (but its supposed to be $7$) or it would be less than $7$, in which case it would floor to something $6$ or less.